# Is this some kind of regex within bash variable instantiation?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

What do those two assignations (i and C omitting the first one to void) do? Is it some kind of regex for the variable? I tried with bash, but so far there were no changes in the output of my strings after instantiating them with `"${i//\\/\\\\}"` or `"\"${i//\"/\\\"}\""`

```
C=''
for i in "$@"; do
    i="${i//\\/\\\\}"
    C="$C \"${i//\"/\\\"}\""
done
```

Comment: Oof. It looks like an attempt to store a list of DOS file paths in a single string by escaping backslashes and double quotes. A first step would be to simply use an array instead: `C=( "$@" )`. The backslashes should be left alone; if `C` knows about DOS file paths, it doesn't need them to be escaped, and if it doesn't, quoting them probably won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${i//\\/\\\\}` is a slightly complicated-looking parameter expansion:

It expands the variable `$i` in the following way:

- `${i//find/replace}` means replace all instances of "find" with "replace". In this case, the thing to find is `\`, which itself needs escaping with another `\`.
- The replacement is two `\`, which each need escaping.

For example:

```
$ i='a\b\c'
$ echo "${i//\\/\\\\}"
a\\b\\c
```

The next line performs another parameter expansion:

- find `"` (which needs to be escaped, since it is inside a double-quoted string)
- replace with `\"` (both the double quote and the backslash need to be escaped).

It looks like the intention of the loop is to build a string `C`, attempting to safely quote/escape the arguments passed to the script. This type of approach is generally error-prone, and it would probably be better to work with the input array directly. For example, the arguments passed to the script can be safely passed to another command like:

```
cmd "$@" # does "the right thing" (quotes each argument correctly)
```

if you really need to escape the backslashes, you can do that too:

```
cmd "${@//\\/\\\\}" # replaces all \ with \\ in each argument
```

Answer (score 2):

It's bash *parameter expansions*

- it replace all backslashes by double backslashes :`"${i//\\/\\\\}`
- it replace all `\"` `by \\"` : `${i//\"/\\\"}`

Check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe